# How do I run tox in a project that has no setup.py?

Tags: python, unit-testing, distutils, tox

I would like to use `tox` to run my unittests in two virtualenvs, since my application has to support 2 different Python versions.

My problem is that `tox` requires a `setup.py`, but I have none since my application is not a module and has its own installer. For now I don't want to go through the hassle of automating the install process as to work with `setup.py`, I just want to run my unittests without having to write a `setup.py`.

Is that possible? Or how can I write an "empty" setup.py that simply does nothing? Can you point me towards some documentation on the subject (the `distutils` documentation explains how to write a meaningful `setup.py`, not an empty one)?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

After digging inside the source code, I found a scarcely documented option in tox.ini that skips sdist:

```
[tox]
skipsdist = BOOL    # defaults to false
```

Setting this to `True` I got what I wanted, saving me the effort of writing a meaningful `setup.py`

Comment: And what is your `tox.ini`'s code that actually runs the tests?

Comment: My tests are run with nosetests: `commands = nosetests {posargs}`

Comment: I run my Django tests with `python manage.py test` so setup.py is not needed there either. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 59):

If you have an application (with a `requirements.txt`), rather than a project that you are going to distribute (which would have a `setup.py` instead), your `tox.ini` should look something like this:

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
deps = -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
```

Found this answer originally from David Murphy's blog, but the page is no longer available, you can find an archived version here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150112223937/https://blog.schwuk.com/2014/03/19/using-tox-django-projects/

(Original link, now dead: http://blog.schwuk.com/2014/03/19/using-tox-django-projects/ )

Comment: If you're going to do this, you might also be looking to set the PYTHONPATH, to do this just do 
`setenv = # newline
 PYTHONPATH = .` under [testenv]

Comment: SO's comment formatting can be confusing at first on conveying what @ZN13 is instructing us. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339689/1877509 on how it looks in a `tox.ini` file.

Answer (score 4):

This is my `tox.ini` file content for Django project by multiple settings:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36-{accounting,content,media}_settings
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
commands = python {toxinidir}/manage.py test
deps = -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt

setenv =
    accounting_settings: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.accounting
    contents_settings: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.contents
    media_settings: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.media
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had to remove `usedevelop = true` from my conf.

My configuration was looking like that:

```
[tox]
envlist = flake8,py36

[testenv]
usedevelop = true
install_command = pip install -U {opts} {packages}
deps =
    py36: -r requirements.txt
    py36: -r requirements-test.txt
    flake8: flake8
commands=
    flake8: flake8 app tests --ignore=E501,W503
    py36: pytest {toxinidir}/tests {posargs}
```

I added `skipsdist = true` as the other answers suggest. But it was not enough. As said above, also removing `usedevelop = true` did the trick.